# Display a confirmation message after a password change

Tags: django, django-forms

After a user succesfull password change I keep the user on the same page named password_change.

**url.py**:

```
path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('password_change')), name='password_change'),
```

I tried using the messages framework with:

**views.py**:

```
def password_change(request):
    password_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if password_form.is_valid():
            password_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)  # <-- keep the user loged after password change
            messages.success(request, 'Your password has been updated', extra_tags='safe')
    return render(request, 'registration/password_change_form.html', {'password_form': password_form})
```

with this in my html :

```
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <p class='{{ message.tags }}'>{{ message }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

And I tried:

**views.py**:

```
def password_change(request):
    success = False;
    password_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if password_form.is_valid():
            password_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)  # <-- keep the user loged after password change
            success = True;
    return render(request, 'registration/password_change_form.html', {'password_form': password_form, 'success': success})
```

with that in my html :

```
            {% if success %}
                <div>Password changed !!!</div>
            {% endif %}
```

The password is changed but I can't display a message to celebrate this wonderful success.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `{{message.tags}}` and just show `{{message}}`?

Comment: Nothing new has happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution.
In this example I redirect to an other page but the principle would be the same if I wanted to redirect on the same page :

**urls.py:**

```
path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name = 'password_change'),
path('edit_profile_alt/', views.CustomPasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password_change_done'),
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name = 'login')
def password_change(request):
    password_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if password_form.is_valid():
            password_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)  # <-- keep the user loged after password change


class CustomPasswordChangeDoneView(PasswordChangeDoneView):
    template_name = 'appName/edit_profile.html'
    extra_context = {'done': 'done'}
```

the html template:

```
{% if done %}
    <p>
        You have a changed your password.
    </p>
{% else %}
```

Good to read if you want to do the same kind of thing : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeDoneView

Answer (score 0):

Might be your success variable is not setting its value to "True". 
In your second method try putting `success=True` before the line `update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)`